# How to avoid tables being split between pages in a Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a template Google Docs where I clone and generate reports. I'm adding tables to these reports populating content. Sometimes all the tables fit in one page but in certain instances they overflow into a second page making a table to split between two pages. I want to avoid this table getting split between pages by pushing this table to the second page.

GAS API does not provide means to disable this or provide information to retrieve the current page or the page numbers. Does anyone have a workaround to avoid the above mentioned scenario? Below is an example code of what I'm doing.

```
function TestFunction() {
  var oFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Z__FOLDER_ID);
  var oReport = DriveApp.getFileById(Z_TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy("TEST", oFolder);
  var oDoc = DocumentApp.openById(oReport.getId());

  var arrTables = oDoc.getBody().getTables();
  var copiedTable = arrTables[2].copy();
  arrTables[2].removeFromParent();

  var iTableCount = 0;

  for(var iHdrIdx = 0; iHdrIdx < 7; iHdrIdx++) {        
    var oCompTable = copiedTable.copy();

    oCompTable.replaceText("<PLCHLDER_1>", "TEST_1");
    oCompTable.replaceText("<PLCHLDER_2>", "TEST_2");

    iTableCount = iTableCount + 1;
    oDoc.getBody().insertTable(13 + iTableCount, oCompTable);
  }

  oDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: I think a workaround might be to break the page before the table with [`appendPageBreak()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendPageBreak()) if you can approximate where the table is likely to end up at the bottom of the page or calc the exact height of elements. Though this is not a trivial task (you can keep track of text elements, char width and heights), it is not impossible with `getMargin{edge}`-esque methods + `getPageHeight()` / `getPageWidth()`

Comment: You could always file a feature request for the Docs API if you'd like to see something like this implemented at [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. @OlegValter I tried to append a page break if the content height is greater than the page height, however there is no API calls to get the height of a table or paragraph element as I see. Is there any other method to keep track of the content height?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - yeah, but as far as I know, the feature requests for page-related info are several years old (I coudn't find the longest thread of 6 years or so I've seen recently, but here is [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36759056))

WebHoundX - yeah, that's not trivial at all (there are indeed no methods to retrieve the height, you have to calculate) - wait a bit, I found myself at compiling a huge answer regarding calculation of height overflow in Google Docs and will post when finished testing :)

Comment: To add to my previous comment, the difficuly is that you have to know the size of elements that come before the element being "pagebreaked", and due to them being nested (even the `PageBreak` is wrapped into `Paragraph`) complexity quickly spirals out of control

Comment: @OlegValter I understood what you were explaining, but since the API does not expose the height of any element in the page I'm stuck. Looking forward for your answer.

Comment: @WebHoundX - phew, that was fun - SO bot check even marked me for captcha to ensure this is not an automated post :) I went through several revisions locally so please let me know if there are any issues / inconsistencies, etc

Comment: @OlegValter Wow. That is a comprehensive answer with detailed explanation. Thank you for that. Let me go through the code thoroughly. Can the logic be influenced by the page margins? I just copied the code and did a test run, and found some false positives. You may see the result here.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GMN0BXR_RtDITTDwd_o-7V5Sql_bD2tm6w89B1_JjOo/edit?usp=sharing

However let me get back after fully examining the code. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi @WebHoundX - yes, I think it might be - there are two possible sources of these positives - one is the unidentified extra margin (I suspect an adjustment takes place during rendering), the second is the unified width of chars (which are in reality kerned, and have different width frequencies). Although judging from the doc, it is likely to be the margins (I'll also check)

Comment: Hi @OlegValter, Did some tests. Pretty impressive thinking. Thank you for that. The result heavily depends on the magic number. And the magic number depends on the top and bottom margin as well as the type of element that is adjacent to the margin. For example if the adjacent element is PARAGRAPH type, body.getMarginTop() + 66 - (body.getMarginTop()/9) would give correct value for top margin, and the same for bottom as well.

Comment: The other false positive is that when all the elements' height perfectly aligns with the page height without overflowing. In this case the first element in the next page becomes positive. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

### Document tree

If you look closely on the [structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) of a Google Doc, you'll notice that it is a tree data structure and not a document in a broader sense (though one might argue that chapter/section/paragraph is also a tree-like structure).

<sub>I suspect the abovementioned is the reason why the API lacks in page related methods - although they are likely be to added in the future</sub>

Since the document is a tree, the problem of determining when a page split occures can be reduced to calculating the point when *the sum of child heights* overflows the page height.

### Problem subdivision

To correctly get the spot at which the split will occure (and keep track of such elements), we need to solve several subproblems:

1. Get the *height*, *width* and *margins* of a page
2. Traverse elements, keeping track of total height. At each step:

   1. Calculate *full* height of the element.
   2. Add the height to total, check if overflow happened.
   3. If total *overflows* page height, the last outermost (closest to root) element is guaranteed to be split. Add the element to list, cache the overflow and reset the total (new page).

### Observations

1. When a `PageBreak` is encountered, total counter can be reset as the next element will be at the top (offset by overflow). Note that as `PageBreak` is not standalone (it is wrapped into `Paragraph` or `ListItem`), it can be encountered at any time.
2. Only the highest `TableCell` in a `TableRow` counts towards total height.
3. Some elements inherit from `ContainerElement`, meaning their height equals to *sum of their children heights* + top and bottom margins.

### Helper functions

First, there are a couple helper functions we can define (see JSDoc comments for details):

```
/**
 * @summary checks if element is a container
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element} elem
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.ElementType} type
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const isContainer = (elem, type) => {
  const Types = DocumentApp.ElementType;

  const containerTypes = [
    Types.BODY_SECTION,
    Types.EQUATION,
    Types.EQUATION_FUNCTION,
    Types.FOOTER_SECTION,
    Types.HEADER_SECTION,
    Types.LIST_ITEM,
    Types.PARAGRAPH,
    Types.TABLE,
    Types.TABLE_CELL,
    Types.TABLE_ROW,
    Types.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS
  ];

  return containerTypes.includes(type || elem.getType());
};

/**
 * @summary gets aspect ratio of a font
 * @param {string} fontFamily 
 * @returns {number}
 * @default .52
 */
const getAspectRatio = (fontFamily) => {
  const aspects = {
    Arial: .52,
    Calibri: .47,
    Courier: .43,
    Garamond: .38,
    Georgia: .48,
    Helvetica: .52,
    Times: .45,
    Verdana: .58
  };

  return aspects[fontFamily] || .618;
};

/**
 * @summary checks if Element is direct child of Body
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element} elem 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const isTopLevel = (elem) => {
  const { ElementType } = DocumentApp;
  return elem.getParent().getType() === ElementType.BODY_SECTION;
};

/**
 * @summary copies non-object array values as is
 * @param {any[]} arr 
 * @returns {any[]}
 */
const shallowCopy = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(el => el);
};
```

### State tracking

Since we have to track overflow, last element processed, etc, I opted to add a `Tracker` object that takes care of state management. Several features of the tracker require an explanation:

`processResults` method:

1. Ensures element bounds (page size) are restored after heights for nested elements have been calced (`setDimensions`, `setMargins`, `resetDimensions` and `resetMargins` methods with private `inits`  allow us to manipulate bounds).
2. Modifies processed heights for specific element types:

   1. Height of `Body` is set to `0` (or it will duplicate child heights).
   2. `TableRow`'s height is set to the highest `TableCell`.
   3. Other type heights are summed with child heights.

`handleOverflow` method:

1. Prevents nested elements from being added to list of splits (can be safely removed).
2. Resets total height to latest overflow offset (height of part of the element split).

`totalHeight` setter:

At each recalc looks for height overflow and invokes overflow handler if needed.

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Tracker
 * @property {Map.<GoogleAppsScript.Document.ElementType, function>} callbacks map of height processers
 * @property {?GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element} currElement current elemenet processed
 * @property {number[]} dimensions exposes dimensions of a page
 * @property {function(): void} handleOverflow handles page height overflow
 * @property {function(): boolean} isOverflow checks if height overflew page height
 * @property {number[]} margins exposes margins of a page
 * @property {number} overflow getter for overflow status
 * @property {function(boolean, ...number): number} processResults process callback results
 * @property {function(): Tracker} resetDimensions restores old dimensions
 * @property {function(): Tracker} resetMargins restores old margins
 * @property {function(): void} resetOverflow resets most resent overflow
 * @property {function(): void} resetTotalHeight resets accumulated height
 * @property {function(...number): void} setDimensions reinits containing dimensions
 * @property {function(...number): void} setMargins reinits containing margins
 * @property {function(string, ...any): void} setStore abstract property store setter
 * @property {number} significantWidth exposes significant page width
 * @property {number} significantHeight exposes significant page height
 * @property {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element[]} splits list of elements split over page
 * @property {number} totalHeight total height
 * 
 * @summary factory for element trackers
 * @param {Tracker#callbacks} callbacks
 * @param {Bounds} bounds
 * @param {Tracker#splits} [splits]
 * @returns {Tracker}
 */
function makeTracker(callbacks, bounds, splits = []) {

  const inits = {
    dimensions: shallowCopy(bounds.dimensions),
    margins: shallowCopy(bounds.margins)
  };

  const privates = {
    bounds,
    current: null,
    currentType: null,
    currOverflow: 0,
    needsReset: 0,
    totalHeight: 0
  };

  const { ElementType } = DocumentApp;

  const ResultProcessors = new Map()
    .set(ElementType.BODY_SECTION, () => 0)
    .set(ElementType.TABLE_ROW, (results) => {
      return results.reduce((result, acc) => result > acc ? result : acc, 0);
    })
    .set("default", (results) => {
      return results.reduce((result, acc) => result + acc, 0);
    });

  return ({
    callbacks,
    splits,

    get currElement() {
      return privates.current;
    },

    set currElement(element) {
      privates.current = element;
      privates.currentType = element.getType();
    },

    get dimensions() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      return bounds.dimensions;
    },

    get margins() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      return bounds.margins;
    },

    get overflow() {
      const { bounds, totalHeight } = privates;
      return totalHeight - bounds.significantHeight;
    },

    get significantHeight() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      return bounds.significantHeight;
    },

    get significantWidth() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      return bounds.significantWidth;
    },

    get totalHeight() {
      return privates.totalHeight;
    },

    /**
     * @summary total height setter
     * @description intercepts & recalcs overflow 
     * @param {number} height
     */
    set totalHeight(height) {

      privates.totalHeight = height;

      if (this.isOverflow()) {
        privates.currOverflow = this.overflow;
        this.handleOverflow();
      }
    },

    isOverflow() {
      return this.overflow > 0;
    },

    handleOverflow() {
      const { currElement, splits } = this;

      const type = privates.currentType;

      const ignore = [
        ElementType.TEXT,
        ElementType.TABLE_ROW
      ];

      if (!ignore.includes(type)) {
        splits.push(currElement);
      }

      this.resetTotalHeight();
    },

    processResults(...results) {
      this.resetMargins().resetDimensions();

      const { currentType } = privates;

      const processed = (
        ResultProcessors.get(currentType) ||
        ResultProcessors.get("default")
      )(results);

      return processed;
    },

    resetDimensions() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      const { dimensions } = bounds;

      dimensions.length = 0;
      dimensions.push(...inits.dimensions);
      return this;
    },

    resetMargins() {
      const { bounds } = privates;
      const { margins } = bounds;

      margins.length = 0;
      margins.push(...inits.margins);
      return this;
    },

    resetOverflow() {
      privates.currOverflow = 0;
    },

    resetTotalHeight() {
      const { currOverflow } = privates;
      this.totalHeight = currOverflow;
      this.resetOverflow();
    },

    setDimensions(...newDimensions) {
      return this.setStore("dimensions", ...newDimensions);
    },

    setMargins(...newMargins) {
      return this.setStore("margins", ...newMargins);
    },

    setStore(property, ...values) {

      const { bounds } = privates;

      const initStore = inits[property];

      const temp = values.map((val, idx) => {
        return val === null ? initStore[idx] : val;
      });

      const store = bounds[property];
      store.length = 0;
      store.push(...temp);
    }

  });
};
```

---

### I. Get page bounds

The first subproblem is trivially solved (the sample might be complex, but is handy for passing state around). Of note here are `significantWidth` and `significantHeight` getters that return width and height that can be occupied by elements (i.e. without margins).

If you are wondering, why `54` is added to top and bottom margins, it is a "magic number" equal to `1.5` default vertical page margin (36 points) to ensure correct page overflow (I spent hours figuring out why there is an extra space of appx. this size added to the top and bottom pages margins despite `HeaderSection` and `FooterSection` being `null` by default, but there seems to be no ).

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Bounds
 * @property {number} bottom bottom page margin
 * @property {number[]} dimensions page constraints
 * @property {number} left left page margin
 * @property {number[]} margins page margins
 * @property {number} right right page margin
 * @property {number} top top page margin
 * @property {number} xMargins horizontal page margins
 * @property {number} yMargins vertical page margins
 * 
 * @summary gets dimensions of pages in body
 * @param {Body} body
 * @returns {Bounds}
 */
function getDimensions(body) {

  const margins = [
    body.getMarginTop() + 54,
    body.getMarginRight(),
    body.getMarginBottom() + 54,
    body.getMarginLeft()
  ];

  const dimensions = [
    body.getPageHeight(),
    body.getPageWidth()
  ];

  return ({
    margins,
    dimensions,
    get top() {
      return this.margins[0];
    },
    get right() {
      return this.margins[1];
    },
    get bottom() {
      return this.margins[2];
    },
    get left() {
      return this.margins[3];
    },
    get xMargins() {
      return this.left + this.right;
    },
    get yMargins() {
      return this.top + this.bottom;
    },
    get height() {
      return this.dimensions[0];
    },
    get width() {
      return this.dimensions[1];
    },
    get significantWidth() {
      return this.width - this.xMargins;
    },
    get significantHeight() {
      return this.height - this.yMargins;
    }
  });
}
```

---

### II. Traverse the elements

We need to recurisvely walk through all children starting from root (`Body`) until a leaf is reached (element without children), get their outer heights and heights of their children if any, all the while keeping track of `PageBreaks` and accumulating height. Each `Element` that is an immediate child of `Body` is guaranteed to be split.

Note that `PageBreak` resets total height counter:

```
/**
 * @summary executes a callback for element and its children
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element} root
 * @param {Tracker} tracker
 * @param {boolean} [inCell]
 * @returns {number}
 */
function walkElements(root, tracker, inCell = false) {
  const { ElementType } = DocumentApp;

  const type = root.getType();

  if (type === ElementType.PAGE_BREAK) {
    tracker.resetTotalHeight();
    return 0;
  }

  const { callbacks } = tracker;
  const callback = callbacks.get(type);
  const elemResult = callback(root, tracker);

  const isCell = type === ElementType.TABLE_CELL;
  const cellBound = inCell || isCell;

  const childResults = [];
  if (isCell || isContainer(root, type)) {
    const numChildren = root.getNumChildren();

    for (let i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
      const child = root.getChild(i);

      const result = walkElements(child, tracker, cellBound);

      childResults.push(result);
    }
  }

  tracker.currElement = root;

  const processed = tracker.processResults(elemResult, ...childResults);

  isTopLevel(root) && (tracker.totalHeight += processed);

  return processed;
}
```

---

### III. Calculate element heights

In general, *full* height of an element is top, bottom margins (or either padding or border) + *base* height. Additionally, as some elements are containers, their base heights equal to the sum of full heights of their children. For that reason we can subdivide the third subproblem into getting:

1. Heights of primitive types (without children)
2. Heights of container types

**Primitive types**

*Text height*

UPD: It is possible for the `getLineSpacing()` to return `null`, so you have to guard against it (default: `1.15`)

`Text` elements consist of chartacters, so to calculate base height one has to:

1. Get parent's indentation
2. Get char heigh and width (for simplicity assume it depends on font aspect ratio)
3. Substract indentation from useful page width (= line width)
4. For each char, add to line width until overflow and increment number of lines then<sup>1</sup>
5. Text height will equal number of lines by char height and apply line spacing modifier

<sup>1</sup> Here, traversal of chars is unnecessary, but if you wanted a greater precision, you could map char width modifiers, introduce kerning, etc.

```
/**
 * @summary calculates Text element height
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Text} elem
 * @param {Tracker} tracker
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getTextHeight(elem, tracker) {

  const { significantWidth } = tracker;

  const fontFamily = elem.getFontFamily();
  const charHeight = elem.getFontSize() || 11;
  const charWidth = charHeight * getAspectRatio(fontFamily);

  /** @type {GoogleAppsScript.Document.ListItem|GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} */
  const parent = elem.getParent();

  const lineSpacing = parent.getLineSpacing() || 1.15;
  const startIndent = parent.getIndentStart();
  const endIndent = parent.getIndentEnd();

  const lineWidth = significantWidth - (startIndent + endIndent);

  const text = elem.getText();

  let adjustedWidth = 0, numLines = 1;
  for (const char of text) {

    adjustedWidth += charWidth;

    const diff = adjustedWidth - lineWidth;

    if (diff > 0) {
      adjustedWidth = diff;
      numLines++;
    }
  }

  return numLines * charHeight * lineSpacing;
}
```

**Container types**

Fortunately, our walker handles child elements recursively, so we only need to process specifics of each containter type (`processResults` method of the tracker will then connect child heights).

*Paragraph*

`Paragraph` has two property sets that add to its full height: *margins* (of which we only need top and bottom - accesible via `getAttributes()`), and *spacing*:

```
/**
 * @summary calcs par height
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Paragraph} par
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getParagraphHeight(par) {
  const attrEnum = DocumentApp.Attribute;

  const attributes = par.getAttributes();

  const before = par.getSpacingBefore();
  const after = par.getSpacingAfter();

  const spacing = before + after;

  const marginTop = attributes[attrEnum.MARGIN_TOP] || 0;
  const marginBottom = attributes[attrEnum.MARGIN_BOTTOM] || 0;

  let placeholderHeight = 0;
  if (par.getNumChildren() === 0) {
    const text = par.asText();
    placeholderHeight = (text.getFontSize() || 11) * (par.getLineSpacing() || 1.15);
  }

  return marginTop + marginBottom + spacing + placeholderHeight;
}
```

Notice the `placeholderHeight` part - it is necessary as when you append a `Table`, an empty `Paragraph` (without `Text`) is inserted equal to 1 line of default text.

*Table cell*

`TableCell` element is a container that acts as body for its childern, thus to calc height of, for example, a `Text` inside the cell, both dimensions and margins (padding *in this context* is the same as margin) of bounds are temporarily set to those of the cell (height can be left as is):

```
/**
 * @summary calcs TableCell height
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.TableCell} elem
 * @param {Tracker} tracker
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getTableCellHeight(elem, tracker) {

  const top = elem.getPaddingTop();
  const bottom = elem.getPaddingBottom();
  const left = elem.getPaddingLeft();
  const right = elem.getPaddingRight();

  const width = elem.getWidth();

  tracker.setDimensions(null, width);
  tracker.setMargins(top, right, bottom, left);

  return top + bottom;
}
```

*Table row*

`TableRow` does not have any specific properties to count toward full height (and our tracker handles `TableCell` heights):

```
/**
 * @summary calcs TableRow height
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.TableRow} row
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getTableRowHeight(row) {
  return 0;
}
```

*Table*

`Table` merely contains rows and simply adds horizontal border widths to the total (only the top [or bottom] row has 2 borders without colliding, so only *number of rows + 1* borders count):

```
/**
 * @summary calcs Table height
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Table} elem
 * @returns {number}
 */
function getTableHeight(elem) {
  const border = elem.getBorderWidth();
  const rows = elem.getNumRows();
  return border * (rows + 1);
}
```

---

### IV. Determine overflow

The fourth subproblem just connects the previous parts:

```
/**
 * @summary finds elements spl  it by pages
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Document} doc
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Element[]}
 */
function findSplitElements(doc) {

  const body = doc.getBody();

  const bounds = getDimensions(body);

  const TypeEnum = DocumentApp.ElementType;

  const heightMap = new Map()
    .set(TypeEnum.BODY_SECTION, () => 0)
    .set(TypeEnum.PARAGRAPH, getParagraphHeight)
    .set(TypeEnum.TABLE, getTableHeight)
    .set(TypeEnum.TABLE_ROW, getTableRowHeight)
    .set(TypeEnum.TABLE_CELL, getTableCellHeight)
    .set(TypeEnum.TEXT, getTextHeight);

  const tracker = makeTracker(heightMap, bounds);

  walkElements(body, tracker);

  return tracker.splits;
};
```

### Driver function

To test that the whole solution even works, I used this driver program:

```
function doNTimes(n, callback, ...args) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    callback(...args);
  }
}

function prepareDoc() {

  const doc = getTestDoc(); //gets Document somehow

  const body = doc.getBody();

  doNTimes(30, () => body.appendParagraph("Redrum Redrum Redrum Redrum".repeat(8)));

  const cells = [
    [1, 2, 0, "A", "test"],
    [3, 4, 0, "B", "test"],
    [5, 6, 0, "C", "test"],
    [7, 8, 0, "D", "test"],
    [9, 10, 0, "E", "test"],
    [11, 12, 0, "F", "test"]
  ];

  body.appendTable(cells);

  doNTimes(8, (c) => body.appendTable(c), cells);

  body.appendPageBreak();

  doNTimes(5, (c) => body.appendTable(c), cells);

  const splits = findSplitElements(doc);

  for (const split of splits) {
    split.setAttributes({
      [DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]: "#fd9014"
    });
  }

  return doc.getUrl();
}
```

The driver function will mark each split element with a background colour (you would probably want to append a `PageBreak` before each of them):

[image: Element split sample]

### Notes

1. The answer is likely to overlook something (i.e. if one full row of a `Table` fits on previous page it won't count as an overflow somehow) and can be improved upon (+will expand with additional classes such as `ListItem` later), so if anyone knows of better solution for any part of the problem, let's discuss (or fire away and contribute directly).
2. Watch for UPD sections for refinements during testing.

### References

1. `ContainerElement` class [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element)
2. `ElementType` enum [spec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type)
3. `Paragraph` class [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph)
4. `TableCell` class [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell)
5. Structure of a [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document)

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me in the Google Doc editor:

1. Create a 1x1 table, with tiny interior font (e.g., 2pt).
2. Set the 1x1 table's row property to NOT "allow row to overflow across pages" - so the 1X1 won't overflow.
3. Paste your actual table into the 1x1 table.

I'm not sure how it would work in the API.